# Maximum Setup Log Size in Group Policy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows-event-log

I want to set a maximum size for the setup log across all the machines in my domain but within group policy I only see GPO settings for maximum application, security, and system logs.  Is there a way to set maximum setup log size in GPO or another way that will replicate to all machines in my domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the idiosyncrasies about the event logs is that while Application, Security, and System are "Administrative" event logs, the Setup log is an "Operational" event log.  That's why not all features and functions apply equally to all of the logs.

I don't see an easy, built-in way of setting this via GPO, but there certainly ways to change it if you're determined enough, and you could conceivably push those changes via Group Policy.

Making the Setup log 64KB larger via Powershell:

```
$EL = Get-WinEvent -ListLog Setup
$EL.MaximumSizeInBytes += 64KB # Must be a factor of 64KB
$EL.SaveChanges()
```

Or, modify it via the registry.  You won't find Operational event logs entries in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` like you might expect.  Instead, you'll find them under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels`.  Under the `Setup` subkey, you will find a DWORD value named `MaxSize`.  Just change that key to something like `0x00200000  (2097152)` if you wanted a maximum log file size of 2048KB.  Remember that the value *must* be a factor of 64KB.

I would personally go for pushing the registry change via Group Policy as that would be much faster for the clients to process than a Powershell script.

Here is a great Microsoft blog article about pushing custom registry changes via Group Policy, and even creating your own custom administrative template if you want to go the extra mile:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2007/08/14/deploying-custom-registry-changes-through-group-policy.aspx